# Group Employees By Year Then By Cost Center

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I have a table of employees that includes their start date, end date and cost center.  Employees have a many-to-one relationship to cost centers.

I need to create a query that counts employees at the end of each year, and within each year by cost center, so the result set might look like this:

[image]

I have no problem getting a count of all employees for the entire organization by year using this query (fiscalYear is just a list of years from fiscalCalender):

```
SELECT  x.fiscalYear ,
        ( SELECT    Count(y.teammateId)
          FROM      teammateHistory y inner join costCenters cC on y.costCenterId = cC.costCenterId
          WHERE     year(y.workStartDate) <= x.fiscalYear
            and y.workEndDate is null
        ) AS Headcount
FROM    fiscalCalendar x
group by x.fiscalYear
```

Just can't figure out how to add a sub-count grouped by cost center for each fiscal year.

Comment: How do you know the years to query? Will they be hard-coded in the query, pulled from a table, is there a limit on how many years?

Comment: I query the table fiscalCalendar to get a list of fiscalYear.  There's no limit on how many fiscal years, but a company will typically only have past years, the current year, plus the next year in a fiscal calendar table.  My query by fiscalYear works fine - I just want to break that down by cost center within each fiscal year.

Comment: What I mean is that in SQL the columns normally have fixed names. So if you want to change the column names based on the query parameters, you would have to do dynamic SQL to pivot the correct column names, which is complex and error-prone. Can we just return columns: `LastLastYear, LastYear, ThisYear, NextYear`?

Comment: Yes those are rows though and it sounds like you want to pivot. Do you need the year numbers in the column headers, or can we just write `LastYear` etc

Comment: My current query by fiscal year already works correctly - output below:

Comment: 2018 111
2019 179
2020 234
2021 247
2022 247

Comment: I need to know the year number - and within the year, how many by cost center.  It's not really a pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You seem to want conditional aggregation.  Without sample data, some of these details might be wrong.  But the basic idea is:

```
SELECT cc.costCenterId,
       SUM(CASE WHEN th.workStartDate < '2021-01-01' and   
                     (th.workEndDate >= '2020-01-01' or th.workEndDate IS NULL)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) as yr_2020,
       SUM(CASE WHEN th.workStartDate < '2020-01-01' and   
                     (th.workEndDate >= '2019-01-01' or th.workEndDate IS NULL)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) as yr_2019,
          . . .
FROM teammateHistory th INNER JOIN
     costCenters cc
     ON th.costCenterId = cc.costCenterId
GROUP BY cc.costCenter;
```

Comment: I think OP needs the calendar as the driving table: `FROM Calendar LEFT JOIN teammateHistory th INNER JOIN costCenters cc ON th.costCenterId = cc.costCenterId ON year(y.workStartDate) <= x.fiscalYear`

Comment: Gordon - that's what I was looking for.  Charlie - you are correct, but the calendar join isn't quite right, but I'll fiddle with it some more to see if I can get it working properly.  Thank you both!